# What forums or websites have an active bitcoin section?

Tags: forum

Which websites have active bitcoin communities with discussion that is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Bitcoin Talk](http://bitcointalk.org/) is currently the most active.

The [bitcoin reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/) also has a fair amount of traffic and discussion.

After that, it falls off pretty significantly.

[Talk Gold](http://www.talkgold.com/forum/f513-.html) has some discussion, so does [bitcoin.org.uk](https://bitcoin.org.uk/forums/).

[bitcoinforums.net](http://www.bitcoinforums.net/index.php) and [other forums](http://www.ugbit.com/forums/forum.php) are sparse. (See link to wiki in Chris Acheson's post for a list of all current forums)

There are of course often discussions about blog posts or news items on tech related blogs like Slashdot, Ars Technica, Wired, etc. The same is true of some sites dedicated to online gambling, and some Tor forums dedicated to the Silk Road and similar projects.

There have also been some longer threads that are especially useful for miners at the [Overclockers Forum](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=674572)

Answer (score 2):

Witcoin. They have an interesting concept to keep spam down: You have to pay to post (using Bitcoins). Revenue gets shared between the site and the poster your replied to.

However, it [appears Witcoin is defunct now](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3512/what-is-the-state-of-witcoin), though.

Answer (score 1):

The bitcoin.it wiki has a [list of forums](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Forums).  [BitcoinTalk](http://bitcointalk.org/) and the [Bitcoin Subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/bitcoin) are currently the most active.  The [bitcoin.org.uk forum](https://bitcoin.org.uk/forums/) has a fair amount of activity too.

Answer (score 0):

Say what you will about how much of a bunch of jerks they are, but somethingawful has a huge bitcoin following. (Just not in the good sense!!)

Answer (score -1):

For people looking for a new way to connect with the Bitcoin world check out CoinConnect
www.CoinConnect.org - a full featured Bitcoin social network.