# What is the state of Witcoin?

Tags: websites, e-wallet, forum

There used to be a forum site called Witcoin. It was interesting in that in order to post, you'd have to pay bitcoins, and when someone replied or upvoted, you made bitcoins.

The site went away.

What is the current state? Are there plans to bring it back? Will there be a chance for users to recover their coins?

Answer (score 3):

Witcoin was written and run by mizerydearia. At some point he became unable to run the site, but he was/is unwilling to give the witcoin database or wallet to anyone else. (Someone else owns the domain name.) Mizerydearia was very intelligent, honest, and active, but it seems likely that he's developed some sort of mental illness (as you'll see if you read his [forum posts](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=338;sa=showPosts)). It's very sad. Hopefully he'll someday recover enough to run witcoin again or at least refund the BTC.

Answer (score 2):

> Apologies for witcoin going down.
>
> I have had a lot of internal issues with the administration of the old
>   site and I hope to recover access to your accounts soon so please stay
>   tuned for updates. For this I humbly apologise. Feel free to submit
>   anything to this blog as I have left it open for you to post things
>   to. Contact me by asking a question and once again, I am  sorry.
>
> Dave , cryptocoinmedia , witcoin.

[Posted 2 months ago](http://witcoin.com/post/18428807281/apologies-for-witcoin-going-down)